# Maintain textview height in LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have two TextViews in LinearLayout. Layout orientation is in horizontal. I have to maintain both Textview height as equal. But as per text length both are shown in different height.

I had tried to make the same text length like below

```
public static String padRight(String s, int n) {

 return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);  

}
```

But height is bit different. How do i solve this ?

Comment: You can fix the layout_height parameter for the textview to some constant value, instead of wrap_content

Comment: can you post the screenshot here please

Comment: give wrap content to the text view which will have higher height and for the another text view give match parent and give wrap content to the linear layout as well.it will work.but not a perfect solution i think.

Comment: please post you xml layout file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand you you want to `TextView`s inside a horizontal oriented `LinearLayout`, and both `TextView`s must in same height.

Then use a layout something like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:background="#B40431"
        android:text="text sample\ntext sample\ntext sample\ntext sample\ntext sample\ntext sample\n"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:text="text sample\ntext sample\ntext sample"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output is going to be this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.I had fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Because the text is long textview getting bigger So You set the singleLine true of your textView then it will work,

Add this line in your Textview xml:--

```
    android:singleLine="true"
```

hope it helps you..

Comment: pls accept & upvote the answer if it helps to solve your issue

Comment: If I use single line, there is no need to consider about TextView Heigth. You had given response for my question. So I had send Thanks message. Aegean's answer is exact one.But before seeing him answer I had fixed that issue.But Answer is correct. So I had accept his answer.Accept and upvote is doesn't matter....